# How to save data form json file in dictionary? Discord.py

Tags: python, json, dictionary, discord.py

To make it short.
I want to save dictionary {'user': amount_of_messages} called **user_messages** to json file.
Next, open this file to be able to update the amount of messages that user has sent.
At the end, save dictionary to json file again.

I want to make some kind of stats that will override.

Here is what I mean:

I save my dictionary with stats to json file, and it works.

```
with open('users.json', 'w') as z:
            json.dump(user_messages, z)
```

But, how do I open this file, and save data to this user_messages dictionary.

Comment: `json.load` is how you open up a json file as a dictionary

Comment: Okay, now i would like to store this data from a file in my user_messages dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a json file as a dict we use `json.load`, then it's just a basic python dict (You should know how to work with them), to save to a json file we use `json.dump`

```py
>>> with open("whatever.json", "r") as f:
...     data = json.load(f)
...
>>> print(data)
{"user": 5}
>>> data["user"] += 5 # Updating the data
>>> print(data)
{"user": 10}
>>>
>>> # Saving the file
>>> with open("whatever.json", "w") as f: 
...     json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

#### Reference:

- [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=load#json.load)
- [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=dump#json.dump)

Comment: Thanks for the aswer, but I've got another question. How can i save loaded data to my own dictionary while I got the same keys in both (file and my dict). Do i have to use loop, to store the values when their keys match? If so, how to do this? I just want to store data from the file in my global dictionary.

Comment: You can use a bot var or a global variable, but my question is, why would you want that? You could simply open the file and read it whenever you want

Comment: Well, actually you're right. I guess i'm over complicating this. Nevermind, thanks for help